# QT Networking Crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting SIGSEGV on accessing the Reply object of a network request. If I do this, it works fine:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;

/**
 * Main entry point.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Configuration configuration;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QNetworkRequest * req = new QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://localhost:5000/status/health"));
    QNetworkReply * reply = manager.get(*req);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]{
        QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
        std::string readStr = read.toStdString();
        std::cout << "Got reply: " << readStr << endl;

        reply->close();
        reply->deleteLater();
    });
    return a.exec();
}
```

But this does a SIGSEGV:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;

void doRequest() {
    QNetworkRequest * req = new QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://localhost:5000/status/health"));
    QNetworkReply * reply = manager.get(*req);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]{
        QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
        std::string readStr = read.toStdString();
        std::cout << "Got reply: " << readStr << endl;

        reply->close();
        reply->deleteLater();
    });
}


/**
 * Main entry point.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Configuration configuration;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    doRequest();

    return a.exec();
}
```

So something is falling out of scope. I couldn't figure out what. So I did this:

```
static QNetworkReply * reply;

void doRequest() {
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://localhost:5000/status/health"));
    reply = manager.get(req);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]{
        QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
        std::string readStr = read.toStdString();
        std::cout << "Got reply: " << readStr << endl;

        reply->close();
        reply->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

And that does NOT SIGSEGV. And I don't have a clue why not.

Am I being really quite stupid about how lambdas work with [&] ? Or is it something magical about what a QNetworkReply object *really* is? Is that really a smart pointer, and because it's fallen out of scope, it's being destroyed?

Does anyone have a pointer to the *right* way to call network functions from within my GUI? I'm doing all this to get this to work on a button click. Maybe I need to keep the reply objects myself and forget about them within that lambda. I don't know. The examples I found were all standalone, like my original code.

Comment: I'd start with running a debugger over this and checking at which line it is crashing. Since you're working with pointers I'd check that these objects actually exist.

Comment: It's crashing on access of the reply object: QByteArray read = reply->readAll(); It appears to be a scoping problem as turning reply into a static variable (that doesn't fall out of scope) resolves the problem. I don't understand *why*, as it's a pointer, not an object on the stack.

Comment: Okay. I think this is me being a lambda idiot. I changed the [&] to [=] and the problem disappears.

Comment: Yes, they're leaking req because I was trying to figure out what was falling out of scope. I've been working on this for a good chunk of the afternoon. It was a lambda idiot problem. [&] instead of [=].

Comment: `req` is leaked btw, better just create it on the stack.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yes. That was an attempt to see if req falling out of scope was the problem. If letting it leak meant I stopped the segv, I could then deal with the leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [&] notation in lambdas is really dangerous. Specially in an asynchronous environment.

So i am gonna show you why:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = manager.get(*req);

QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]{
    QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
    std::string readStr = read.toStdString();
    std::cout << "Got reply: " << readStr << endl;

    reply->close();
    reply->deleteLater();
});
```

You are capturing the reply pointer BY REFERENCE. At the end of the scope, the reply pointer is destroyed and you have a reference to garbage.

The solution is capture the reply pointer BY VALUE:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = manager.get(*req);

QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply]{
    QByteArray read = reply->readAll(); // Works well, it's a fresh copy of the pointer
    std::string readStr = read.toStdString();
    std::cout << "Got reply: " << readStr << endl;

    reply->close();
    reply->deleteLater();
});
```

Comment: Ya. I've been away from C++ for 2 decades and am still catching up to C++11 and 14. I think when dealing with some form of promises/futures/async, then it's critical to use =. When dealing with more immediate use, & is safe. 95% of my current lambdas are only referencing this, which is passed by value regardless, so I haven't been burned before. I'll switch my pattern to avoid this in the future. I lost most of an afternoon due to a single character in my code.